# How to write dict in file with specific format and headers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key

I have a dict:

```
dictionary1 = {100: {num: 1, age: 2, line: 3}}
dictionary2 = {90: {num: 1, age: 50, line: 4}}
```

I need to write this data into file line by line in the following format:

```
# HEADER 100 #
1 1 2 3
# HEADER 90 #
1 1 50 4
```

How to do that using Python?

Comment: What in particular are you having trouble with? Show us the code you've written so far, and explain where you're seeing unexpected behavior, or where you have found the documentation to be unclear.

Comment: I make this at first so, should I use libs or how to do that?

Comment: what are num, age, line? Are they strings?

Comment: Yes, it is strings, but can be a number too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in dictionary1:
  print('HEADER ',i)
  print('1 '+' '.join([str(x) for x in list(dictionary1[i].values())]))
```

You can change dictionary1 to dictionary2 for other values.

Comment: So, i can use f.write() instead print to write this in file, right?

Comment: yes, I think so.

Comment: What is it `i`?

Comment: i is the variable, you can use any character